# Copy a title attribute to the next 3 anchor tags

Tags: jquery, copy, title

I am really trying to break out of the little jQuery box that I have been in, and trying some different things with jQuery to just shorten time on certain projects, and I am wondering what is the best solution if I just want to copy the title attribute from one anchor, and set that value to the next 3 anchor tags. Seems tedious, I know... Here is what i tried so far.

```
$('#home-gallery li a').each(function(){
    var copiedTitle = $(this).first().attr('title');
        $('#home-gallery li a').each(function(){
            this.title = copiedTitle;
        });
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
    <li>
    <a href="images/tn/eowine/full.jpg" data-fancybox-group="eowine" title="Eowine vs. Nosgule"><img src="images/tn/eowine.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <!-- more images -->
    <div style="display: none;">
      <a href="images/tn/eowine/first.jpg" data-fancybox-group="eowine" title="Eowine vs. Nosgule"><img src="images/tn/eowine/first.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      <a href="images/tn/eowine/second.jpg" data-fancybox-group="eowine" title="Eowine vs. Nosgule"><img src="images/tn/eowine/second.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      <a href="images/tn/eowine/third.jpg" data-fancybox-group="eowine" title="Eowine vs. Nosgule"><img src="images/tn/eowine/third.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thank you!

---

Thank you guys so much for helping me out, it means a lot... I definitely improved my knowledge on this subject, and it's help from the community that I appreciate the most!

I will go ahead and try the various tricks presented to me, and will research every method posted to grasp the knowledge even further.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: `$('#home-gallery li a + div a')` will select all `a` tags inside `div`, which is after your `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$anchors = $('#home-gallery li a');
$anchors.slice(1, 4).attr('title', $anchors.first().attr('title'));
```

What this does is select the 2nd to 4th elements of the matched collection (which includes all anchors) and setting their `title` attribute to match the title of the first element in the collection.

If you had other criteria than strict 2nd-3rd-4th positioning there would be a similar way to express those as well.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/MJuUY/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
var copiedTitle = $('#home-gallery li a:first').attr('title');

$('#home-gallery li a:not(:first)').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', copiedTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one each.

```
var copiedTitle = $('#home-gallery li').children('a').attr('title');
$('div a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title') = copiedTitle;
});
```

Children selects only direct descendants, and since your first anchor has the original title, and it's not a sibling of subsequent anchors, it's the only one that needs grabbed and stored.